# how to Prevent Css Inheritance when a webpage is embeded inside a Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I am using jquery and visual studio 2010.

I have used div and a PlaceHolder inside it.

I am able to render a web page inside my Div.

but when i use site like www.google.com the menu bar at the 
top of the page doesn't render inside my div it inherits in my aspx page.

I don't want to use Iframe.
is there any Alternative to achieve this.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your DIV with an iframe - it is designed to contain external content, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanx for the help but i don't want to use Iframe